# Ant Migration Tool - Order of Package.xml File Matter?

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, migration

Does the order of the package.xml file matter? For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>Idea</members>             
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>UserLicense</members>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

Would this cause issues if the Apex Classes, Components, Visualforce page, or Apex Triggers were dependent on some of the objects being in place? Would this work better with a setup like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>Idea</members>             
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>UserLicense</members>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

I would assume the order doesn't matter, but I am just looking for someone to verify that assumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never seen it make a difference.  There are a lot of dependencies, anyway, Visualforce w/ Apex, Apex w/ Custom Objects, etc.  Just as long as those dependencies are referenced in the package.

Comment: +1 for this, been using it for years in many different setups over hundreds of different package.xml's. Never seen order matter, within or across types. If order ever did matter, it would almost certainly be a bug.